# How Do I Set Classpath with tectia and ksh?

Tags: java, ssh, classpath, ksh

I am using SSH tectia Client. I want to set my classpath. 
I am using :`

```
EXPORT CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/testvis/standard`
```

and it is showing `ksh: EXPORT not found`

What am I missing? How do I correctly set the classpath?

Answer (score 2):

`export` **not** `EXPORT`.

```
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/home/testvis/standard"
export CLASSPATH
```

**or**

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/home/testvis/standard"
```

And, if `/home/testvis` is your home folder, then you could do

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$HOME/standard"
```